# Question about the close-loop AC-Sweep simulation result of ADA4625-1 using LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I'm using LTspice XVII (newest version), the simulation model of ADA4625-1 I downloaded from AD's official site.

I'm going to design an inverting voltage amplify circuit with a gain of -10.

[image]

The simulation circuits are as below:

---

1. Open-loop frequency response test, the result is consistent with the datasheet, with a 0dB cutoff frequency greater than 10MHz. And it's similar to a single-pole ideal opamp with -20dB/dec over a wide frequency range.

### [image]
[image]

2. A model I built for the feedback loop.

ADA4625-1's input capacitance is 20pF (11pF of CM, 9pF of DM), and I added a 10pF stray capacitance of PCB.

To compensate for the pole generated by Cin and Ri, I added a zero by feedback Capacitance, Cf = 0.1 * Cin.

[image]

The AC result of Noise gain is plotted below marked as red lines.

**And the frequency of the junction is about 1.25MHz, which I think is corresponded to the -3dB cut-off frequency of the closed-loop.**

[image]

---

But the closed-loop simulation shows a much lower -3dB(20-3=17dB) cut-off frequency of 50kHz.

[image]
[image]

Which can't satisfy my need for closed-loop bandwidth.

---

Please tell me what's the problem, is my simulation model not accurate, or is there some bug in ADA4625-1's SPICE model?

If my simulation circuit is wrong, please tell me how to fix it.

Thanks a lot!

[simulation source file](https://ez.analog.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/1020/ADA4625_5F00_AC.asc)

Robert

Comment: When you run an ac analysis in SPICE, always check the dc operating point, e.g. what is the output voltage of your op-amp in your configuration? Make sure the op-amp dc output lies in a linear region, away from \$V_{cc}\$ and \$V_{ee}\$ and add some dc bias to the modulating source \$V_2\$.

Comment: Why did you make an autogenerated symbol when the device is already available in the database? Just press `F2` and type `4625`. Even it it hadn't, you're much better off using the `[Opamps]/opamp2` symbol and adding the correct `.inc` or `.lib`. Anyway, for some reason, I can't get an open loop response, not with `4625` or `4625-1` or `4625-2`. That might be a sign that the model has problems. Using `UniversalOpamp3b` with `Aol=31meg GBW=18meg Slew=45meg` shows a similar output to the `4625-1` with the same feedback.

Comment: To answer Verbal's concern. The OPAMP's power supply is +-5V, the input offset is set to 0, which is in the linear input region of ADA4625

Comment: To answer "a concerned citizen"'s concern, the integrated model sometimes differs from the official model downloaded from Analog.com in some features. The downloaded model clarifies that the open-loop frequency response is modeled.

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed this problem.

By modeling in Mathematica software with a simplified OP-AMP dual-poles math model, I find that my LTspice open-loop simulation circuit is inaccurate because my input signal should firstly be filtered by Ri and Ci, hence producing a new pole Ri-Ci in both the Open-loop response and the Closed-loop response.

$$
f_p=\frac{R_i+R_f}{2\pi R_f R_i(C_i+C_f)}\approx \frac{1}{2\pi R_i C_i}
$$

A more dedicated model can illustrate this:

[image]
In this model, the input stimulus firstly is attenuated by block 'm'. And this model clearly shows the influence of the additional pole Ri-Ci.

Thanks again for all your kind suggestions and help!